# How to get accessToken for graph api when inside the teams application for tab app?

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, msteams-react-base-component

I am building a Microsoft Teams tab app using React, and I need to access the Microsoft Graph API to fetch some data for the signed-in user. How can I obtain an access token for the Microsoft Graph API when my app is running inside the Teams application?

I have already installed the @microsoft/teams-js package as a dependency in my project and integrated the Teams SDK into my app.